# Polymorphism and object storage

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

0I'm quite rusty at C++. I've tried various searches but can't come up with an answer. I have the following code:

```
class Base
{
  public:
    Base() {};
    virtual void hello() { std::cout << "I'm the base class" << std::endl; }
};

class Alice : public Base
{
  public:
    Alice() {};
    virtual void hello() { std::cout << "I'm Alice" << std::endl; }
};


class Bob : public Base
{
  public:
    Bob() {};
    virtual void hello() { std::cout << "I'm Bob" << std::endl; }
};


Base test(int alice)
{
  if(alice)
    return Alice();
  else
    return Bob();
}


int main()
{
  Base a = test(0);
  Base b = test(1);

  a.hello();
  b.hello();
}
```

I would expect the output to be

```
I'm Alice
I'm Bob
```

but instead it is

```
I'm the base class
I'm the base class
```

What (aside from Python-on-the-brain) is going on here?

Comment: You're getting [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Comment: Side-note:  You had damned well better implement a `virtual` destructor in the base class!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of `test` is `Base`. That means it returns `Base`s and `Base`s only. No `Alice`s or `Bob`s will be returned from that function. When you do `return Alice();` or `return Bob();` the `Base` parts of those objects get *sliced* out and returned.

Likewise, the objects `a` and `b` in `main` are of type `Base` and that's all they'll ever be. That's why, when you call `hello` on them, you are invoking the `Base` implementation.

In C++, you can take advantage of polymorphism by using *pointers* or *references*. That is, a `Base*` or a `Base&` can point at or refer to an `Alice` or a `Bob` object. Then, when you attempt to call a virtual member function through that pointer or reference, the appropriate implementation of the function will be determined by looking at the run-time type of the object.

As a simple test, you could dynamically allocate your `Alice` and `Bob` objects and return a pointer to them:

```
Base* test(int alice)
{
  if(alice)
    return new Alice();
  else
    return new Bob();
}
```

You'll need to make `a` and `b` have type `Base*` and then call hello with, for example, `a->hello()`. However, if you dynamically allocate objects like this, you have to remember to `delete` them. Better, use a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr`, for which polymorphism will still work.

Also note that if you want to use these types polymorphically, you should implement a virtual destructor.

Comment: Besides all of that's correct, all the points already are well known under the term of [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)!

Comment: *Shaking fist at sky* Poiiiiiiiiinters!!!